# find and delete object from nested JSON by its key value

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to delete an object inside a nested JSON. As in example below, my aim is to delete the maths from the object. But I have to search the "mat" key and delete it. in my actual case, there are 10s of objects in subjects property.

```
 const obj = {
       "id":"1234",
       "name":"John Doe",
       "level":"elementary",
       "subjects":[
          {
             "key":"mat",
             "name":"maths",
             "teacher":"Mr Smith",
          },
          {
             "key":"eng",
             "name":"english",
             "teacher":"Mrs Smith",
          }
       ],
       "homeroom_teacher":"Mrs Brown"
    }
```

after the deletion I want to have:

```
 const obj = {
       "id":"1234",
       "name":"John Doe",
       "level":"elementary",
       "subjects":[
          {
             "key":"eng",
             "name":"english",
             "teacher":"Mrs Smith",
          }
       ],
       "homeroom_teacher":"Mrs Brown"
    }
```

Comment: JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would filter

```js
const obj = { "id":"1234", "name":"John Doe", "level":"elementary", 
  "subjects":[ 
    { "key":"mat", "name":"maths", "teacher":"Mr Smith", }, 
    { "key":"eng", "name":"english", "teacher":"Mrs Smith", } 
  ], "homeroom_teacher":"Mrs Brown" };
 
const keep = ["eng"]; // assuming more could be present

obj.subjects = obj.subjects.filter(({key}) => keep.includes(key))

console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an iterative solution using [object-scan](https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan). Vanilla js might be preferable, depending on your use case. This solution aims to be flexible

```js
// const objectScan = require('object-scan');

const myObj = { id: '1234', name: 'John Doe', level: 'elementary', subjects: [{ key: 'mat', name: 'maths', teacher: 'Mr Smith' }, { key: 'eng', name: 'english', teacher: 'Mrs Smith' }], homeroom_teacher: 'Mrs Brown' };

const remove = (obj, k) => objectScan(['subjects[*].key'], {
  abort: true,
  rtn: 'bool',
  filterFn: ({ value, gparent, gproperty }) => {
    if (value === k) {
      gparent.splice(gproperty, 1);
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
})(obj);

console.log(remove(myObj, 'mat'));
// => true

console.log(myObj);
/* => {
  id: '1234',
  name: 'John Doe',
  level: 'elementary',
  subjects: [ { key: 'eng', name: 'english', teacher: 'Mrs Smith' } ],
  homeroom_teacher: 'Mrs Brown'
} */
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/object-scan@15.0.0"></script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)